# Colorbar for two contour plots

Tags: python, colorbar

I have two contour plots but I want the colorbar to apply to both.  My code so far is shown.  How can I create a single colorbar that can be applied to both plots?

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.tri as tri
    import scipy, pylab
    x=[14.86,   14.48,  14.09,  13.70,  13.32,  12.93,  12.54,  12.16,  14.82,  14.43,  14.04,  13.65,  13.26,  12.87,  12.48,  12.09,  14.16,  13.71,  13.26,  12.82,  12.37,  11.92,  11.47,  11.02,  13.48,  12.96,  12.44,  11.93,  11.41,  10.90,  10.38,  9.86,   12.79,  12.21,  11.62,  11.04,  10.45,  9.87,   9.29,   8.70,   12.10,  11.48,  10.85,  10.23,  9.60,   8.98,   8.35,   7.73,   11.72,  11.08,  10.44,  9.79,   9.15,   8.51,   7.87,   7.23]

    y= [0.00,   0.00,   0.00,   0.00,   0.00,   0.00,   0.00,   0.00,   3.17,   3.17,   3.17,   3.17,   3.17,   3.17,   3.17,   3.17,   6.43,   6.43,   6.43,   6.43,   6.43,   6.43,   6.43,   6.43,   9.60,   9.60,   9.60,   9.60,   9.60,   9.60,   9.60,   9.60,   12.77,  12.77,  12.77,  12.77,  12.77,  12.77,  12.77,  12.77,  16.03,  16.03,  16.03,  16.03,  16.03,  16.03,  16.03,  16.03,  19.20,  19.20,  19.20,  19.20,  19.20,  19.20,  19.20,  19.20]

    z=[80.73,   81.75,  82.44,  82.81,  82.85,  82.57,  81.97,  81.04,  82.75,  83.78,  84.54,  85.01,  85.19,  85.09,  84.71,  84.04,  87.38,  88.11,  88.82,  89.50,  90.14,  90.76,  91.35,  91.91,  91.33,  92.04,  92.84,  93.73,  94.71,  95.79,  96.95,  98.21,  93.24,  94.24,  95.30,  96.41,  97.57,  98.79,  100.06, 101.39, 94.10,  95.35,  96.59,  97.83,  99.06,  100.29, 101.52, 102.74, 94.39,  95.77,  97.11,  98.41,  99.66,  100.86, 102.02, 103.14]

    z1=[84.18,  84.96,  85.49,  85.77,  85.81,  85.59,  85.13,  84.42,  86.23,  87.02,  87.63,  88.03,  88.25,  88.27,  88.10,  87.73,  91.09,  91.28,  91.64,  92.19,  92.92,  93.82,  94.90,  96.16,  94.83,  94.99,  95.46,  96.23,  97.30,  98.69,  100.37, 102.36, 96.42,  96.90,  97.64,  98.65,  99.91,  101.44, 103.23, 105.28, 97.02,  97.81,  98.79,  99.95,  101.29, 102.82, 104.53, 106.43, 97.16,  98.16,  99.28,  100.51, 101.86, 103.33, 104.91, 106.61]
    plt.subplot(121)
    triang = tri.Triangulation(x, y)
    plt.tricontour(x, y, z, 15, linewidths=0.5, colors='k')
    plt.tricontourf(x, y, z, 15, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
    plt.plot(x, y, 'ko', ms=3)
    plt.xlim(min(x),25)
    plt.ylim(min(y),25)
    plt.xlabel('e')
    plt.ylabel('d')
    plt.title('title1')
    plt.subplot(122)
    triang = tri.Triangulation(x, y)
    plt.tricontour(x, y, z1, 15, linewidths=0.5, colors='k')
    plt.tricontourf(x, y, z1, 15, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
    plt.plot(x, y, 'ko', ms=3)
    plt.xlim(min(x),25)
    plt.ylim(min(y),25)
    plt.xlabel('e')
    plt.ylabel('d')
    plt.title('title2')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just add a separate set of axes then add the colorbar to those. Something like:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.9, 0.1, 0.05, 0.9])
fig.colorbar(z1, cax=ax2) #specifies to put the colorbar in ax2
```